# Why can't i open a port in vultr server?

Tags: server, centos, port

The port 22 and 80 are open, because I can use ssh to link the server and view the website built on it through 80. But later I build another service which will use port 2368. I can't open it.

I am using a centos stream 9 x64

I tried firewall-cmd to open it. And I tried using iptables, where I add port 2368 to INPUT accept of iptables.

To be honest, when i deploy the server, I open the port 80 only with few steps. Now, I go through the same steps for port 2368 but It don't work.

I am sure the service is running well, because when I use nginx to proxy pass to 2368, I can view the page.